# access a global reference list in ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, reference, global-variables, ocaml

I have this code:

```
let l = ref []

(*then I have this tail-recurse function 
that is supposed to recalculate with a certain formula 
all the values that are in the global reference list.*)

let f (a:int) (b:int) = 
   (*here I want to put the new values a and b in the 
     l - list and then do my calculations with all the contents 
     in l*)
```

So maybe someone can show me via an example how this could be done.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you get an error of some kind? Assuming you know both how to access a ref cell and a list, I struggle to see how combining them could be all that much more challenging.

Comment: @glennsl I did. With ```let f (a:int) (b:int) = a::b::l;; let rec sum = match l with |[]->0 |x::xs->x+sum;;``` But this seems to always override the old values in the list.

Comment: Remember that `l` is not a `int list`. It's an `int list ref`.  `a :: b :: l` won't compile.

Comment: @Chris so is it even possible in OCaml to save and change the list by appending new values to it?

Comment: Yes. @Butanium posted an answer showing exactly how to 3 hours ago. You really would be well advised to review a basic OCaml tutorial. If you are being instructed, there is no harm in supplementing it.

Comment: It's worth noting that lists are well-suited to a functional programming style, but you are pursuing a very imperative programming style in OCaml.

Answer (score 2):

```ml
l := a :: b :: !l;
(* Your code here *)
```

Will do the job. `l := foo` assign `foo` as the new value to `l` and `!l` access to the value stored in `l`